# Nothing showing up at output with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I know the function works for the button and it does get number, and I can print the `Num` variable but when I set it as the output string it seems to not show up in the output text. I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong with the output_str.set function or the `textvariable` function, but I can't figure out what exactly.

Does not throw any errors btw.

```
import tkinter as tk
def clicked():
    num = (entry_int.get())
    Num = num * 0.45
    output_str.set = (Num)
   


window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Pounds to kilos")
window.geometry('350x200')

title = tk.Label(window, text = "Pounds to Kg", font = "helvectica" )
title.place(x = 115)

entry_int = tk.IntVar()
txt = tk.Entry(window, width = 15, textvariable = entry_int)
txt.place(x= 129, y= 30)

output_str = tk.StringVar()
output = tk.Label(window, fg = "blue", textvariable = output_str, font = "helvectic")
output.place(x= 126, y= 50)


btn = tk.Button(window, text = "Calculate",fg = "red", command = clicked )
btn.place(x = 240, y = 26)

window.mainloop()
```

I tested the output text and tested that it was actually getting the input numbers.

I'm expecting the `Num` variable to be displayed in the output label.

Answer (score 0):

> Nothing showing up at output with tkinter

- You cannot set `StringVar()` in  `Label` widget.
- Change coordinate of `y` layout. So we can see `Label` output. It is hidden behind
- Add `.configure` to update in `Label` output `clicked()`.
- Add float for Entry in `clicked()`

That all. You ready to go.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk
def clicked():
    num = float(entry_int.get())
    Num = num * 0.45
    print(Num)
    output.configure(text=Num)
   


window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Pounds to kilos")
window.geometry('350x200')

title = tk.Label(window, text = "Pounds to Kg", font = "helvectica" )
title.place(x = 115)

entry_int = tk.IntVar()
txt = tk.Entry(window, width = 15, textvariable = entry_int)
txt.place(x= 129, y= 30)

#output_str = tk.StringVar()
output = tk.Label(window, width= 20, bg = "white",  font = "helvectic")
output.place(x= 126, y= 60)


btn = tk.Button(window, text = "Calculate",fg = "red", command = clicked )
btn.place(x = 240, y = 26)

window.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]